# Spartacus: Wrong currency code in cart API parameters

Tags: spartacus-storefront

We have implemented multisite configuration recently, but facing an issue after it.
When we have it configured (in both mode - Static/Dynamic configuration), we are getting error in cart API when refreshing the page. After analyzing it we found that it is happening due to wrong site context parameter(currency code) and it is happening only in case of non SSR build, when we use SSR it works fine. In case of normal build, it is adding “USD” as currency code in API call with dynamic site binding and if we are using static binding then it is picking the first currency code even if we are on secondary website. Spartacus framework is picking it from default list of currency codes when hitting cart API on page refresh.

Spartacus version:2.0

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQ8oi.jpg)

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGOHv.jpg)

Please share a solution on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `currency` in static configuration (e.g. adding `currency: ['JPY'],` inside `context`, currency will be `JPY`).

If your multiple sites using different "currency" (e.g. one site uses "USD" and the other one uses "JPY"), then you cannot use static configuration. Dynamic configuration loads all base sites data, and get the default currency from each site (the value is: the `defaultCurrency` of the first store in the site). So, you need make sure the site data is set correctly in backend.

Comment: Thank you for quick response!
We are already using dynamic configuration but currency is not being used from base sites data. 
When we have cart data and refresh it, the cart call doesn't have correct defaultCurrency from base sites data. It seems it is picked up from currency constants present in Spartacus framework and default value is USD, which is not a supported currency from any of our sites or stores. Any API call after it has correct currency code updated in it. It seems cart call is happening without waiting for base sites data.
Please suggest any fix for this issue in framework.

Comment: What is your cart request? `lang` and `curr` are appended to each OCC call; and `curr` is the active currency.

Comment: It is OOTB cart request which happens when user has items in cart and then refreshes the page or revisit the site. In such case framework itself calls the cart API. So no custom or explicit call here, only OOTB framework call.